# Flex-wrap:wrap doesn't wrap when I am changing browser's width

Tags: css, flexbox

I have added all properties. When I am changing browsers width they start to stick to each other, it is not working because I have too many images?

Can't wrap images to new line:
[image]

```css
#skills>div {
  margin-top: 80px;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

```html
<section id="skills">
  <h3>skills</h3>
  <div>
    <div><img src="./img/python.png">
      <h5>Python</h5>
    </div>
    <div><img src="./img/js.png">
      <h5>Javascript</h5>
    </div>
    <div><img src="./img/vue.png">
      <h5>Vue.js</h5>
    </div>
    <div><img src="./img/nodejs.png">
      <h5>Node.js</h5>
    </div>
    <div><img src="./img/mongodb.png">
      <h5>MongoDB</h5>
    </div>
    <div><img src="./img/express.png">
      <h5>Express.js</h5>
    </div>
    <div><img src="./img/babel.png">
      <h5>Babel.js</h5>
    </div>
    <div><img src="./img/npm.png">
      <h5>NPM</h5>
    </div>
    <div><img src="./img/html.png">
      <h5>HTML</h5>
    </div>
    <div><img src="./img/css.png">
      <h5>CSS</h5>
    </div>
    <div><img src="./img/sass.png">
      <h5>Sass</h5>
    </div>
    <div><img src="./img/boostrap.png">
      <h5>Bootstrap</h5>
    </div>
    <div><img src="./img/jquery.png">
      <h5>Jquery</h5>
    </div>
    <div><img src="./img/ajax.png">
      <h5>Ajax</h5>
    </div>
    <div><img src="./img/restful.png">
      <h5>RESTful</h5>
    </div>
    <div><img src="./img/heroku.png">
      <h5>Heroku</h5>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Can't get why it is not working.

Comment: Seems to work https://fiddle.jshell.net/sgq97xam/ . Maybe you have some more css overwriting your rules?

Comment: I attached a photo. Click link in my question text

Comment: its working fine, can you include a url to your page?

Comment: The photo doesn't help us to understand what's going on. could you provide a fiddle reproducing your issue? or provide some more code in your question?

Comment: Check www.oolooq.io

Comment: You mean #skills>div{min-width:150px}?

Answer (score 1):

You have specified this

```
#skills > div > div {
    width: 15%;
}
```

Change it to flex-basis: 15%, and you can use media queries to alter that property in a way that is more suitable for mobile/tablet devices.

Comment: To elaborate my answer, you didnt specify flex-basis value so it defaults to auto, but since you specified width property that value is used and it takes precedence over flex-basis: auto. Thats why your elements didnt wrap on smaller resolutions, they took 15% width of available space and your images didnt have set max-width property so they overlapped a bit.